# mysql: not able to retrieve data which is in between <> symbols

Tags: php, mysql

Am running a sql query with php to retrieve some data from mysql database.
Everything works well except that, if the data contains symbols like < and >, then whatever data present between these symbols doesnt show in the output.

for example, if the data is something like "`<hello there>  how are you?`"  then only "`how are you?`" is shown.

But when i run the query directly, it shows me everything without missing anything.

I have done this before, but I cannot remember on the top of my head as what exactly I did. And google is not helping me today, slow day for me.... :(

Comment: are you using the data in HTML? Unless you encode it properly, most likely those are being treated as tags and quietly ignored

Comment: How do you display the results ? With database manager such as SQLYog or from a programming language such java,c,php ,etc. ? If it's a programming language you'll need to show us the code that displays the results.

Comment: when i display the results using php, it shows me data between the tags missing, but when i run the query over phpmyadmin, it shows me all the rows with all the data.

Comment: Retagged with php. If what you say is true then your problem necessarily comes from your php code. Please show us the code you are using.

Comment: Who down-voted this question?? whats the reason???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape your databse response properly using [`htmlentities()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$sql = 'SELECT row_with_text FROM your_table';
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo htmlentities($result['row_with_text']);
```

phpMyAdmin does the escaping for you, but it's your responsibility to escape text for HTML in your application.